# PHP - How to upload files to a common directory from subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, subdomain, distribution

I have a project that have 3 modules and each is running on subdomain like

- http://admin.myproject.com
- http://operator.myproject.com
- http://myproject.com

All three are pointed to different directories but on the same server. When I uplaod file from http://operator.myproject.com, it is moved in /var/www/html/operator/uploads/{{operator_id}}/picture_name.jpg, when I do from admin, it is moved in /var/www/html/admin/uploads/{{id}}/picture_name.jpg

From http://myproject.com, is there any way to upload all the files to any centralized directory on server that is accessible by all projects and I can download the files easily??

I am using `Laravel` as a backend

Comment: the server-side code handling the uploads is completely under your control. Put the files wherever you want them.

Comment: Can I move the files out side of the project directory??

Comment: php couldn't care less what the structure of your site's document root is. It isn't bound by any docroot restrictions. It can access anything/anywhere on your server that the webserver's userID has access to.